# grails 3.0.x url mapping dose not work

Tags: grails-3.0

1. where should i put class UrlMappings? under grails-app/conf/ or grails-app/controllers ??
2. the UrlMappings is below

   ```
   class UrlMappings {
   static mappings = {
       "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
           constraints {
               // apply constraints here
           }
       }

       "/checkpreload.htm"(view: "checkpreload")
       "500"(view:'/error')
       "404"(view:'/notFound')
   }
   }
   ```

checkpreload.gsp is under views folder, there is no controller associated with it, and it works in grails 2.4.4, but if i put the UrlMappings under controllers folder, return 404, if i put it under grails-app/conf, the return will be

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'checkpreload' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

plz help, i want to access a gsp file without controller associated

Comment: How do you run your app ? It seems there's an issue with running from Application.groovy but grails run-app displays views without any problem. By the way, UrlMappings has to be in controller folder.

Comment: command "gradle bootRun" and "grails run-app" got the same error. the grails version is 3.0.1, the java version is 1.8.0.40, the UrlMappings is under controllers folder, the error message is "13:44:09.943 56283 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'checkpreload' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'] with root cause"

Comment: Same problem here, using Grails 3.0.9 with UrlMapping.groovy in the Controller directory. Workaround would be e new Controller with a basic method only to automatically do the mapping for you